# Zero delay loop

Tags: verilog, simulation

When we are run the design, we are getting the "Zero Delay loop" issue.
What is the meaning of "**Zero Delay loop**" and

1. Why this issue will present.
2. What are the causes for zero delay loop.

The simulator is continuously running and it's not finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Why Zero delay loop happened?**

   Due to race condition or ambiguous coding style zero delay loop may get generated which results in simulation hung or infinite simulation time
2. **What are the causes of Zero delay loop?**

   One example of a common loop behaviour as follows:

   ```
   always @ (x)
   begin
     y = 1'b0;
     ...
     case (x)
       ...
       1'b1: y = 1'b1;
       ...
     endcase
   end

   always @ (y)
   begin
     x = 1'b0;
     ...
     case (y)
       ...
       1'b1: x = 1'b1;
       ...
     endcase
   end
   ```

Here in this there is a possibility of loop when both `x` and `y` are set to 1, which causes new event and trigger case statements called zero delay loop because of event triggering at same time, to avoid use #0 delay which forces event to happen at the end of the time step, but this type of coding style is not recommended

3. **To debug this issue**

From my understanding vcs has a switch called +vcs+loopreport which will generate a detailed report of zero delay loop and genrerate a text file, from that you can either eliminate or debug those loops effectively

Comment: Do you know the filename that is generated?